# What does due diligence on you checked out means?

Tags: translation

If I have contacted someone who wanted to check how I am good at something, and after checking the status I have received an email saying:

> 'Peter' told me that the due diligence on you checked out.. We are
>   waiting etc.

what does the due diligence mean in this sense.

On google it says: "`reasonable steps taken by a person to avoid committing a tort or offence.`", but what does "checked out" part means?

Comment: :) I am pretty sure they haven't meant on the police records, but mostly on my expertise, but I got the point ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Checked out" means that there was nothing concerning after they investigated the matter at hand.

Answer (score 4):

> what does the due diligence mean in this sense.

Here, [***due diligence***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Due_diligence) means "*an investigation of a business or person prior to signing a contract, or an act with a certain standard of care.*"

> but what does "checked out" part means?

It means the investigation found nothing objectionable.